# "Published computer scientist" in Russian?

Tags: выражения, терминология, word

How to say in Russian "published computer scientist"?

Comment: What do you mean by "published"?

Comment: @OlegLobachev Someone who published at least one peer reviewed article

Comment: "Специалист по информатике, автор статей в рецензируемых изданиях" or something along those lines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer a half of your question, "computer science" is typically (after German and French, I guess) referred to in Russian as `информатика`.

There is, actually, a thin veil of differences between possible terms.

- Computer science, used as a direct loan from English, is specially about computers. Duh.
- `Информатика`, the standard word in, e.g. German for the field, could also be directly translated as "informatics" in English, even if very seldom. It is about *information processing* though, which is a wider term.
- The older `кибернетика`, loaned directly from "cybernetics" has fallen out of grace. It's about automatic systems and information processing, detached from the medium and way of processing. It's almost never used in the West, in the East there was a historic crack-down on it (and also on genetics), so it's mostly remembered by native-speakers for that. I've never seen this term used for computer science in a serious context.

The usage of names for modern partial areas varies. For example, "data science" is mostly taken verbatim, while "deep learning" is typically translated to `глубокое обучение`.

---

Now, someone doing a science is a scientist (`ученый`), or a studied professional (`специалист`). I infer "published" as "had published research", but I am unsure. In this case it's something compound as `специалист, публиковавший научные работы в области информатики`.

Comment: `специалист с публикациями по информатике`

Comment: Yes. Or if the main point is about being a researcher, then `ученый`, `научный сотрдник` and so on.

Comment: I would use `теория вычислений`, it sounds much less dorkish.

Comment: That's a _very_ different area. Theory of computing is very roughly about _how do we compute stuff_, it's almost numerical mathematics. Computer science (or, rather "informatics") is about information processing. _How we transform and navigate data? What is the way to do some kind of data manipulation? How hard is it to perform it?_